# Can variables in the local scope get reverted after global function has been declared?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i=7
def myfunc():
    i=2
    global i
    i=i+3
    print(i)
    print(i)
myfunc()
```

My book gives the output to be:

```
10
2
```

It says the variable `i` is re-assigned back to 2 which does not make sense to me as I learned global can't be reverted back from a different book.

When running the code I get an error saying "i is defined before global declaration" which I understood by reading previous questions on this site.

So my question would be, why has my book plastered this code and its variations everywhere if it is wrong? Is it from a previous version? I do not have a complete understanding of python and its previous version as I study computer science only to pass high school. And does global get reverted here?

Comment: You are saying `global i` one line too late

Comment: @DeepSpace they know, the question is why is this code used as an example in a book.

Comment: "So my question would be, why has my book plastered this code and its's variations everywhere if it is wrong?" That sounds like something you should ask the authors and publishers

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact code that is used in the book, including the exact indentation? I'm suspecting that for example the second `print(i)` is supposed to be outside the function (i.e., not indented). Can you show a photo of the code in the book?

Comment: It is entirely possible the book is just bad. There's a genuinely impressive amount of terrible programming documentation out there.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Nope, this is the exact code. Given its frequency I assumed there to be some logic and importance behind the question. I think il move on. Thanks guys.